# Merge user accounts: error message only after submit

Tags: feature-request, merge-accounts

I was trying to merge my two accounts, but I accidentally did from Meta instead of the main site.

After I entered all the information and pressing the submit button, the following error message occurs:

[image: Screenshot]

This does not comply with Martin Fowler's fail fast principle.

Suggestions:

- fail fast option: use JavaScript to inform me about this problem as soon as I select the entry, not after submitting
- allow merging from Meta: I don't see much of a difference between my Meta account and my normal account. After a merge I expect both of them being merged anyway.